# Detecting input type support of date and datetime types?

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I try to use Modernizr to detect the support for `date` and `datetime` input fields (HTML5), but those variables always return `false`, even when they are supported (i.e. in Chrome):

```js
if(Modernizr.inputtypes.datetime) {
    jQuery("#what").html("Yes, I know datetime input fields.");
} else {
    jQuery("#what").html("Sorry, what is a datetime input field?");
}
```

```css
#what {
    padding : 2em;
    margin  : 2em;
    text-align : center;
    
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="what">Well... I'm not sure.</div>
```

By researching this problem [it seems this bug is an old habit](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/63).

How can I solve it?

Comment: For non modernizr, please look at https://gomakethings.com/how-to-check-if-a-browser-supports-native-input-date-pickers/

```
var isDateSupported = function () {
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 var value = 'a';
 input.setAttribute('type', 'date');
 input.setAttribute('value', value);
 return (input.value !== value);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` is not supported on `chrome` or `firefox`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

For future ref you can use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/

Use `Modernizr.inputtypes['datetime-local']` or `Modernizr.inputtypes['date']` instead

Comment: Yes you are right, I was using `datetime-local`, so I have to use `Modernizr.inputtypes['datetime-local']` and this works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is `if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date)` and not `datetime`, as there is no input type called datetime.

Comment: There is an input type `datetime` and `Modernizr` has this object, too. Whatsoever, I had to use `datetime-local` with `Modernizr.inputtypes['datetime-local']`. Thanks anyways.